# facebook "apprequests" with Custom URL?

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I have simple question, I am developing facebook app and using this code to make app requests

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',message: 'Invite friends'}, requestCallback);
```

I want to set custom url when the user accept the request.
for example: stackoverflow.com

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

If a user clicks 'Accept' on a Request, they will be sent to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request with the request_ids

https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]

To do a custom URL
1) store the request_id in your application with the custom link
2) with the user accepts the link read the request_id and fire the custom url

Comment: I tried to save request id to my db for trace it. But I can only store request id and to . But I need to store sender, game name, game id and also request id. I pass it to function. But the callback url didn't returns

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a parameter for a url in the API, but you could use the data parameter for it.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', data: "http://stackoverflow.com" ,message: 'Invite friends'}, requestCallback);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests